# How to make calculation inside annotate?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This one when I run generates error

```
qs = User.objects.annotate(days=(datetime.now() - F("created_at")).days)
```

```
AttributeError: 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'days'
```

How can I make that calculation as an annotation

When I run this code, it wroks fine

```
qs = User.objects.annotate(days=(datetime.now() - F("created_at")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a combination of `ExpressionWrapper`, which tells django what the output field type should be, and `ExtractDay` which, well, extracts the day.

In this case, the output field is a timedelta object (i.e `DurationField`).
`ExtractDay` is just a DB-level function which the django ORM provides.

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay

qs = User.objects.annotate(
    days=ExtractDay(
        ExpressionWrapper(
            datetime.now() - F("created_at"), output_field=DurationField()))
    )
```